# How to set the From email address for mailx command?

Tags: shell, email, solaris, ksh, mailx

I am working on a KornShell (ksh) script running on a Solaris server that will send out an email when and error condition is met.  I am sending the email via `mailx`.

**Question:**  How do I set the "From" email address on the `mailx` command?

**Current Code:**

```
echo ${msg_txt} | mailx -s "Script Failure" ${to_email}
```

Note:  The command works fine, however, the "From" is the name of the user I am running the script as and I would like for this to another email address.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the "-r" option to set the sender address:

```
mailx -r me@example.com -s ...
```

Comment: This is troubling for me because the man page of mailx says: "-r address
    Sets the From address. Overrides any from variable specified in environment or startup files. Tilde escapes are disabled. The -r address options are passed to the mail transfer agent unless SMTP is used. This option exists for compatibility only; it is recommended to set the from variable directly instead."   ...specifically the trailing bit "This option exists for compatibility only....."

Answer (score 45):

The "-r" option is invalid on my systems. I had to use a different syntax for the "From" field.

```
-a "From: Foo Bar <foo.bar@someplace.com>"
```

Comment: In my case, onan Ubuntu 16.04, using your `-a` option, it does show the `Foo Bar` name in the received mail, but a reply to the received mail offers my gmail email address, used as smtp login, instead of the `foo.bar@someplace.com` one.

Comment: This should be considered as a proper answer.

Comment: i faced error: "From: Foo Bar <foo.bar@someplace.com>" No such file or directory

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but when looking at man of mailx I see this: "-a file - Attach the given file to the message." ; which doesn't seem to line up neatly with "adding a From: header"?

Answer (score 25):

In case you also want to include your real name in the from-field, you can use the following format

```
mailx -r "me@example.com (My Name)" -s "My Subject" ...
```

If you happen to have non-ASCII characters in you name, like My AEÆoeøaaå
(Æ= C3 86, ø= C3 B8, å= C3 A5), you have to encode them like this:

```
mailx -r "me@example.com (My =?utf-8?Q?AE=C3=86oe=C3=B8aa=C3=A5?=)" -s "My Subject" ...
```

Hope this can save someone an hour of hard work/research!

Comment: In case anyone's curious, the `=?utf-8?...?=` bit is a [MIME encoded-word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word).

Comment: The real name part of this doesn't work for me on solaris.  The message successfully sends and has the proper email from, but each email I send the from is stripped down just to the email address.

Comment: @Rune Your method returns (My AE??oe??aa??) any idea why?

Comment: @RafaSashi I'm guessing this is because your system is not set up to show UTF-8 characters (2-byte Norwegian characters in this case). On my Norwegian (UTF-8) system it reads "my AEÆoeøaaå"

Comment: Adding the `-a "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"` header solved my UTF-8 letters issue. Now the `é` is properly displayed.

Answer (score 14):

On debian where `bsd-mailx` is installed by default, the `-r` option does not work. However you can use `mailx -s subject recipient@abc.com -- -f sender@abc.com` instead. According to man page, you can specify sendmail options after `--`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, guess I should have read the synopsis in more detail. Unfortunately stuck with horrible bsdutils, glad to have a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately the [DSA 3104-1 security update](https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-3104) broke this method. Instead, the heirloom-mailx package can be installed, which does provide a `-r` option.

Comment: I just installed `bsd-mailx` version `Version: 8.1.2-0.20160123cvs-2`, albeit on an Ubuntu 16.04 system; the `-r` option works.

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into this syntax problem on a CentOS 7 machine.

On a very old Ubuntu machine running `mail`, the syntax for a nicely composed email is

```
echo -e "$body" | mail -s "$subject" -a "From: Sender Name <$sender>" "$recipient"
```

However on a CentOS 7 box which came with `mailx` installed, it's quite different:

```
echo -e "$body" | mail -s "$subject" -S "from=Sender Name <$sender>" "$recipient"
```

Consulting `man mail` indicates that `-r` is deprecated and the 'From' sender address should now be set directly using `-S "variable=value"`.

> In these and subsequent examples, I'm defining `$sender` as `"Sender Name <sender.address@domain.tld>"` and `$recipients` as `"recipient.name@domain.tld"` as I do in my bash script.

You may then find, as I did, that when you try to generate the email's body content in your script at the point of sending the email, you encounter a strange behaviour where the email body is instead attached as a binary file ("ATT00001.bin", "application/octet-stream" or "noname", depending on client).

This behaviour is how Heirloom mailx handles unrecognised / control characters in text input. (More info: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1136493, which itself references the mailx man page for the solution.)

To get around this, I used a method which pipes the generated output through `tr` before passing to `mail`, and also specifies the charset of the email:

```
echo -e "$body" | tr -d \\r | mail -s "$subject" -S "from=$sender" -S "sendcharsets=utf-8,iso-8859-1" "$recipients"
```

In my script, I'm also explicitly delaring the locale beforehand as it's run as a cronjob (and cron doesn't inherit environmental variables):

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF8" ; export LANG ;
```

(An alternate method of setting locales for cronjobs [is discussed here](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/89596/15460))

More info on these workarounds via https://stackoverflow.com/a/29826988/253139 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3120227/253139.

Comment: Note: The mailx package as used on RH-like distros (but also SLES) is actually the `heirloom mailx` which is more sophisticated than the `BSD mailx`. It has SMTP support and many different variables can be set via `-S` option. If you have a choice then go for `heirloom mailx`.

Comment: Appreciate that detail @reichhart, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

The package `nail` provides an enhanced mailx like interface. It includes the `-r` option.

On Centos 5 installing the package `mailx` gives you a program called `mail`, which doesn't support the `mailx` options.

Comment: Note: The mailx package as used on RH-like distros (but also SLES) is actually the `heirloom mailx` which is more sophisticated than the `BSD mailx`. It has SMTP support and many different variables can be set via `-S` option. If you have a choice then go for `heirloom mailx`.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Bionic 18.04, this works as desired:

`$ echo -e "testing email via yourisp.com from command line\n\nsent on: $(date)" | mailx --append='FROM:Foghorn Leghorn <fleghorn@yourisp.com>' -s "test cli email $(date)" -- recipient@acme.com`

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Sierra, creating ~/.mailrc with smtp setup did the trick:

```
set smtp-use-starttls
set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=youremail@gmail.com
set smtp-auth-password=yourpass
```

Then to send mail from CLI:

```
echo "your message" | mail -s "your subject" to_email@gmail.com
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question