# mailx sending message as bin attachment

Tags: linux, perl, mailx

I have a Perl script which is supposed to send an email, with the content consisting of lines of the form

```
key = value
```

The resulting message is sent out by the Perl command

```
`echo "$msg" | 
   mailx -r $WEBMASTER_EMAIL -s "$field{'subject'}" $field{'email'}\n`;
```

This works fine when the values are standard ASCII. However, it doesn't work when extended characters are part of any of the values. Instead of text, the email contains an ATT000001.bin file containing the key value pairs.

Is there a parameter I can send to mailx to stop it doing this, or a recommended way I convert my values so that mailx handles them correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a hard req to use mailx as opposed to MIME::Lite library?

Comment: Sortof, because I'm fixing issues with an old application and I want to make the minimum of changes

Comment: Minimum fixes way => Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3120168/2139766 . It suggests way to tweak mailx command line options. If it does not work then use may use `sendmail` program directly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem today, and I found this question via Google.  :-)

In my case, I was trying to email the output of a curl command, which unfortunately mixes `\r\n` and `\n`.  As a result, `mailx` treats the content as binary and does the weird file attachment thing -- `ATT000001.bin`.

Assuming you can modify the Perl script, try this:

```
$msg =~ s/\r\n/\n/g;  # convert Windows newlines to UNIX newlines
$msg =~ s/\r/\n/g;    # convert bare carriage returns to UNIX newlines
`echo "$msg" | 
    mailx -r $WEBMASTER_EMAIL -s "$field{'subject'}" $field{'email'}\n`;
```

Alternatively, from a shell script (my case), try this:

```
echo "$msg" | perl -p -e 's/\r\n/\n/g; s/\r/\n/g' | mailx ...
```

More information from Redhat: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1136493