# Perl sends email as attachment

Tags: perl, mailx

My question is similar to [mailx sending message as bin attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344813/mailx-sending-message-as-bin-attachment/70589139), but none of the solutions listed there worked for me.

On the contrary, the email is always sent as attachment, even if I remove all the line breaks.

Below, there is my Perl code:

```perl
my $cmd = "/usr/bin/mailx $Email_SendCharsets -s \"$hostname: $subject\" $Email_Auth -r $retAddr $addresses";
my $rc = open3(\*CHLD_IN, \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_ERR, $cmd);
if ($rc != 0)
{
    print CHLD_IN $message;
    close CHLD_IN;
    ... other things here ...
}
... other things here ...
```

Any idea why this is happening?

PS: I'm running the code with Perl 5.10 on RHEL 8.x

Comment: I guess `open3` comes from [IPC::Open3](https://perldoc.pl/IPC::Open3), right?

Comment: @choroba yes exactly

Comment: Does the message contain any characters below `\x20` (a space)?

Comment: I've also tried removing all the unprintable characters from the message before printing it, but without success.

Comment: Not enough information to proceed further.

Comment: Just tell me what other information you need :)

Comment: The best thing would be a script that I can run and experience the problem myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I ended up implementing the sending of the e-mail with just the `Net::SMTP` module. Here the code, if somebody needs it:

```perl
if (my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtpHost, Debug => $Debug)) {
    if($smtp->auth($username, $password)) {
        $smtp->mail($retAddr);
        $smtp->to(@recipients);

        $smtp->data();
        $smtp->datasend("To: $recipientsString\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Subject: $hostname: $subject\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=$charset\n");
        $smtp->datasend("\n");
        $smtp->datasend("$message\n");
        $smtp->dataend();
    }

    my $rc = $smtp->ok();
    if($rc == 0) {
        my $errorMessage = $smtp->message();
        LogError("Mail error: $errorMessage. Msg subject: $subject.");
    }
    $smtp->quit();

    return $rc;
} else {
    LogError("SMTP connection failed. Msg subject: $subject.");
}
```