# Remove host name from sender description mailx

Tags: mailx

When I use this to send a mail I get the sender address as `(root)<noreply@rediff.co.in>` where `root` is the host name .

```
mailx -s 'Spammers `date -d "-1 days" +%Y-%m-%d`' mail_id1@gmail.com,mail_id2@gmail.com -- -r 'noreply@gmail.com'
```

Either I want to remove the host name completely in the sender description or specify another name.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

I have also tried the same as mentioned by Rune in this question [How set the From email address for mailx command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296979/how-set-the-from-email-address-for-mailx-command) which doesn't seem to work.

```
mailx -s 'Spammers `date -d "-1 days" +%Y-%m-%d`' mail_id1@gmail.com,mail_id2@gmail.com -- -r 'noreply@gmail.com (Anonymous)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had done to solve it. I just added -F 'Sender Name'

```
mailx -s 'Spammers `date -d "-1 days" +%Y-%m-%d`' mail_id1@gmail.com,mail_id2@gmail.com -- -F 'Spam Alert' -r 'noreply@gmail.com'
```